# React / TypeScript serviceWorker Update function warning how to resolve

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

When I try to `npm run build` I get this error:

```
Failed to compile.

src/serviceWorker.js
  Line 38:36:  Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return


// Update a service worker
/* eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals */
self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
  let cacheWhitelist = ['biordle']
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map((cacheName) => {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName)
          }
        })
      )
    })
  )
})
```

Here is the error-resulting code:

```
Failed to compile.

src/serviceWorker.js
  Line 38:36:  Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return
```

A more complete version of the code can be found at this Github Repo: https://github.com/Brayman30/biordle

Comment: where does `caches` come from?

Answer (score 1):

It complains because you are returning only in the `if` statement:

```
cacheNames.map((cacheName) => {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName)
          }
        })
```

You should use filter before of map if you want to execute the promise only if `cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1` :

```
cacheNames.filter((cacheName) => cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) ).map((cacheName) => caches.delete(cacheName)
```